# What is the use of configuration file in consul/config when consul client registers the services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I understand that services can be registered through Consul clients, and JSON configuration files can be loaded to `consul/config` to register services when the Consul server is running as a docker container, but why should we register services in 2 places?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an instance of the service running on both the clients and the servers? I believe you need to let Consul know about each node that is running an instance of a service.

Answer (score 0):

Consul is designed for services to be registered against a Consul client agent which is running on the same host where your service is deployed. Services can be registered with an agent either through [configuration files](https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/services) *or* the [/v1/agent/service/register](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#register-service) HTTP endpoint.

Each Consul client agent in the data center submits its registered service information to the Consul servers. The servers then aggregate this information to form the service catalog (https://www.consul.io/docs/architecture/anti-entropy#catalog).

Normally you would not configure the servers to register services which are running on different hosts in the environment. An exception to this when the service exists on a host which does not have its own Consul client agent. In that scenario, the service is considered an external service, and can be registered into the Consul catalog using a different registration/monitoring method. See the tutorial [Register External Services with Consul Service Discovery](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-registration-external-services) for more info.